# Setting date to local variable from data query - "No tabular expression statement found"

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I am unable to set a scalar date value from a query to a local variable. I get the following error:

```
SYNTAX ERROR

No tabular expression statement found
```

**Query:**

```
let startTime = toscalar(customMetrics
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| summarize min(timestamp));
```

I get a result just fine when running just the query:

[image: Log Analytics results]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey Dave, friendly reminder to upvote and accept if Dmitry's answer helped you out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd need to execute a statement/query with this function, otherwise it's just a function definition that does not get called. The easiest one is print command, but you can also invoke the function within some query:

```
let startTime = toscalar(customMetrics
| where timestamp > ago(10m)
| summarize min(timestamp));
print startTime
```